# How to find some specific element in a set?

Tags: python, set

Given some set of tuples (x,y):

```
set([(1,2),(3,4),(3,2),(1,4)])
```

How do I find each tuple with the property (1,z) in the set?

In this example the edges (1,2),(1,4).

EDIT: Is there some other data structure that would support such a request?

Comment: Set's are not designed for that (in terms of algorithmic complexity). There is nothing you can do without iterating all items (and filter) or querying all potential 1,z candidates (without exploiting hash-algorithms in use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comprehension (set or list):

```
In [145]: st = set([(1,2),(3,4),(3,2),(1,4)])

In [146]: [(i, j) for i, j in st if i == 1]
Out[146]: [(1, 2), (1, 4)]

In [147]: {(i, j) for i, j in st if i == 1}
Out[147]: {(1, 2), (1, 4)}
```

Or if you don't want the result in a container, i.e. you just want to loop over the results, etc. you can use a function approach by using the built-in `filter` function:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, st)
```